# How to make legends using python loop for each line/curve when making multiline plot from a list of text files by loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, matplotlib-basemap

My code for creating multiline plot from a list of file using python is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob

path = '/Users/atikulfarazi/Data/HVSR-Obspy-Test/20160924/AoA5'

files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.txt", recursive=True)]

for f in files:
    data=np.loadtxt(f)
    X=data[:,0] 
    Y=data[:,1] 
    plt.loglog(X, Y) #label="*.txt")
    plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('H/V')

plt.show()
```

It is working well. But can't make legend for each line creating loop. Also, can't control other properties of the figure like figure size.